# Keyword based search in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was doing a keyword based search in an asp.net mvc application from a sql database.

The database has a table Resources which has entries of the following format:

resource
english pdf
maths elementary book
english vocabulary

The user is then asked to enter a query which generates the resource which matches the query:

e.g. The user enters "Get all english books"

```
query = "Get all english books";
```

I first tokenise the query string and push the contents into an array:

```
string[] keywords = query.Split(' ');
```

I do a keyword based match with all the keywords with all the entries in the table. If any of the keywords are present in any of the resources I return that row.

Since I don't know what would be the number of keywords prior, I have to write a dynamic query string. Here is the code that I have written:

```
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                    // Tokenize the query 
                    String[] tokens = searchQuery.Split(' ');
                    if (tokens.Length != 0) {
                        string query = "SELECT * FROM Queries WHERE query LIKE '(%'" + "@0" + "'%)'";
                        for (int i = 1; i < tokens.Length; i++)
                            query += " OR query LIKE '(%'" + "@" + i + "'%)'";
                        query += ";";
                        Console.WriteLine("The query is : " + query);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@"+i, tokens[i]);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This does not generate the expected output. Can somebody has experience with this.

Comment: whats expected output? what did you get? the Console.ReadLine() might be blocking it

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the output you are getting and a sample of the output you wish to get.  Without this information it's hard to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem.